# How to simulate an HTTP 500 error on my Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, internal-server-error

I want to simulate this error so I can check the custom HTTP 500 page is displayed, not the default one.

Comment: change your htaccess to something idiotic with wrong syntax :)

Answer (score 2):

Throw a .htaccess with some weird symbols in your document root and call the page

You can break one of the RewriteRules of WordPress if you already have a .htaccess
Just make sure you know what you broke haha

Answer (score 1):

If you deliberately break some code on the site it should display the 500 page.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm you can't have **custom** 500 error page on wordpress as far as i know.

But give this a try on your .htaccess and let know ;)

```
ErrorDocument 500 /500.shtml
```